# CSS Grid - Playing with order of a NxN table in layouts

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I need to make a product comparison table for 3 products. Each has an image (a), title (b), and description (c). I have created this table layout using CSS Grid as:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1a | 1b | 1c |
| 2a | 2b | 2c |
| 3a | 3b | 3c |

So all these entries are in separate `div` cells. This is fine on the desktop. On mobile, I need it as:

|  |
| --- |
| 1a |
| 2a |
| 3a |
|  |
| :----: |
| 1b |
| 2b |
| 3b |
|  |
| :----: |
| 1c |
| 2c |
| 3c |

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0ymv1utL/

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto auto;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.container > div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  /* .container {
     grid-auto-flow: row; 
   } */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1a</div>

  <div class="item">1b</div>

  <div class="item">1c</div>

  <div class="item">2a</div>

  <div class="item">2b</div>

  <div class="item">2c</div>

  <div class="item">3a</div>

  <div class="item">3b</div>

  <div class="item">3c</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to hack this kind of structure with the given HTML? Any lead is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

For the media query you use flexbox:

**Figure I**

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

For the ordering the divs by group use the flexbox property `order`. Apply each one to the inline `style` attribute in HTML (see **Example A**):

**Figure II**

```html
  <div class="item" style='order: 1'>1a</div>

  <div class="item" style='order: 4'>1b</div>

  <div class="item" style='order: 7'>1c</div>
<!--:
    :
    :-->
</section>
```

If you don't want any inline styles mucking up your HTML, here's a CSS solution for a styleheet or `<style>` tag. (see **Example B**)

**Figure III**

```css
.item:first-of-type {order:1}
.item:first-of-type + .item + .item + .item {order:2}
.item:first-of-type + .item + .item + .item + .item + .item + .item {order:3}
.item:nth-of-type(2) {order:4}
.item:nth-of-type(2) + .item + .item + .item {order:5}
.item:nth-of-type(2) + .item + .item + .item + .item + .item + .item {order:6}
.item:nth-of-type(3) {order:7}
.item:nth-of-type(3) + .item + .item + .item {order:8}
.item:nth-of-type(3) + .item + .item + .item + .item + .item + .item {order:9}
```

As seen on this screenshot, it stacks in the order OP requested.

[image: 320x480 Portrait Screen]

### Example A (Inline Style)

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto auto;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="container">

  <div class="item" style='order: 1'>1a</div>

  <div class="item" style='order: 4'>1b</div>

  <div class="item" style='order: 7'>1c</div>

  <div class="item" style='order: 2'>2a</div>

  <div class="item" style='order: 5'>2b</div>

  <div class="item" style='order: 8'>2c</div>

  <div class="item" style='order: 3'>3a</div>

  <div class="item" style='order: 6'>3b</div>

  <div class="item" style='order: 9'>3c</div>

</section>
```

### Example B (Stylesheet)

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto auto;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}

.item:first-of-type {order:1}
.item:first-of-type + .item + .item + .item {order:2}
.item:first-of-type + .item + .item + .item + .item + .item + .item {order:3}
.item:nth-of-type(2) {order:4}
.item:nth-of-type(2) + .item + .item + .item {order:5}
.item:nth-of-type(2) + .item + .item + .item + .item + .item + .item {order:6}
.item:nth-of-type(3) {order:7}
.item:nth-of-type(3) + .item + .item + .item {order:8}
.item:nth-of-type(3) + .item + .item + .item + .item + .item + .item {order:9}
```

```html
<section class="container">

  <div class="item">1a</div>

  <div class="item">1b</div>

  <div class="item">1c</div>

  <div class="item">2a</div>

  <div class="item">2b</div>

  <div class="item">2c</div>

  <div class="item">3a</div>

  <div class="item">3b</div>

  <div class="item">3c</div>

</section>
```